# TinyMCE - link tool, target dropdown list - failed position

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using a standard TinyMCE setup however I have a problem.
When I want to insert a link (using the link tool) the popup window opens as expected.

From there I want to select the link target option. When I click on this it's supposed to open a dropdown, with the option for selection.

While the options appear, the dropdown list is positioned at the bottom of the view instead of under the dropdown selector as one would expect.

I been trying to find a solution via Google and Stack Overflow threads but I haven't yet had any luck.

I have also tried to manipulate the DOM but can't find a way to reposition the dropdown list under the selector when the select is clicked.

I am using the TinyMCE version 4.7.7 from 2018-02-19.

Thanks for your time.

---------- UPDATE -------------

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fnp5729w/) provided to show problem

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.7.7/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
    </script>
    <h2>test</h2>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate the issue as described on TinyMCE 4.6.7 or 4.7.9. In both of those tests, the dropdown menu for link target selection appears under the dropdown selector. Below is how the menu appears in TinyMCE 4.6.7 in my testing:

[image: Example showing a dropdown in TinyMCE 4.6.7]

Is this the only dropdown that displays this behavior?

Do you have other styling or frameworks in place that may be changing the behavior of dropdown menus?

Here is a blank Tiny Fiddle:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab

You can set the TinyMCE version in the left sidebar. Can you replicate the problem there? If not, then it is likely some other part of the application is affecting dropdown behavior.

Comment: I am using bootstrap, and select2. it could be select2. let me test it out.

Comment: You are right good sir. tried to do it on a empty page. it worked, so something is fucking it up. thanks for your help.

Comment: Nevermind that . just fund out that it doesn't matter. it moves the dropdown list down, depending on how far down i scrolled the page before oping it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JS Fiddle you are using an older TinyMCE release.  If you update to the latest TinyMCE 4 (4.9.5) the issue does not happen any more in my testing.  If you update your JS fiddle to use this script for TinyMCE:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.9.5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

...do you still see this happening?